# In a $2 \rightarrow 2$ scattering, is the matrix element always momentum-independent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, kinematics, scattering

I have the same problem as in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/633407/how-to-integrate-the-phase-space-volume-for-2-2-scattering-processes).

Basically the problem is that it looks like the scattering amplitude is being pulled out of the momentum-integrals even though it might not be momentum-independent, to arrive at an expression where $\text{d}\sigma \propto \vert M\vert^2 \text{d} \Omega$.

My idea was the following way to think about this: For two final particles there are in total six integrals to be performed to obtain the total cross-section. Due to the four-dimensional $\delta$-function four of these integrations can (at least in principle) be done quite easily and simply enforce energy and momentum conservation. The two remaining integrals (whichever ones are chosen) can be expressed as an integral over $\text{d}\Omega$, since $\text{d}\Omega$ also contains "two degrees of freedom". And thus $\text{d}\sigma \propto \vert M\vert^2 \text{d} \Omega$ holds intuitively.

Conclusion: It only looks like the scattering amplitude is pulled out of *all* the integrals, even though it isn't.

Is my thinking correct? (If so, I'll post an answer to the original question, just wanted to make sure I'm not mistaken (and I can't comment yet, which is why this is in a new question, not as a comment on the original one))

Comment: From what I see, you do not have any integrals here. You only talk about differential cross-section.

Comment: "For two final particles there are in total six integrals to be performed to obtain the total cross-section", is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Why only six? There are 4 for every four-momenta, which are two. So you have eight integration variables. Then momentum conservation gets rid of 4 of them, leaving you with only four remaining variables. These can be parametrised in polar coordinates where the radial one is the modulus of the four momenta.

Comment: That's something that confused me in your answer to the original question. As far as i know, theres only three for every 4-momentum. See for example equation 11.21 and 11.23 in the textbook by Srednicki (can be found [here](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html)). Additionally, it is somewhat implausible that there schould be integrals over all four components of each four-momentum, since these are four-momenta of particles that are on-shell. Thus their energies are (with a known mass) determined by the three spacelike momenta components.